# AD LDS - LDAP - How to set group's rights on container

Tags: permissions, ldap, windows-server-2012-r2, ad-lds

I installed AD LDS on a W2012R2. Everything is working fine. Now, I want to create new Roles, to grant to groups permissions to create/modify/delete users in a certain container. (I used this [article](http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=34))

For example, this is my instance :

OU=extra,DC=domain,DC=local
|--CN=LostAndFound
|--CN=Roles
|--|----CN=Administrators (Created by default)
|--|----CN=Readers        (Created by default)
|--|----CN=Users          (Created by default)
|--|----CN=AdminGroupCustomer1 (Created by myself)
|--OU=Users (Created by default, I just chose the name and type)
|--|----CN=Customer1
|--|----|--CN=Users
|--|----|--|--CN=user1
|--|----|--CN=Groups
|--|----|--|--CN=group1
|--|----|--CN=Administrators
|--|----|--|--CN=Admin1
|--|----CN=Customer2
|--|------| ...

I want to permit to AdminGroupCustomer1 group the permissions to modify anything in OU=Customer1, but nothing on Customer2.

So this is what I did :

1°) Add **AdminCustomer1** (which is a AD user in fact ), to **AdminGroupCustomer1** group. *OK*
2°) Add **AdminGroupCustomer1** (which is the Group role) to **Readers** group role. *OK* (Is that really needed ? ... I don't think so).
3°) Execute the following DSACLS.EXE command to grant permission on Customer1's container to AdminGroupCustomer1 group:

```
dsacls.exe "\\server:port\CN=Customer1,OU=Users,OU=extra,DC=domain,DC=local" /I:T /G "CN=AdminGroupCustomer1,CN=Roles,OU=extra,DC=domain,DC=local:GW"
```

Where ***/I:T*** is here to apply rights to objects and sub-objects. And ***/G*** is for GRANT rights. ***GW*** is Generic Write permissions.

But I'm still not able to modify user1's password while connected to the instance with an AD users that is member of AdminGroupCustomer1. I tried : ***WP*** = Write Property and ***WD*** = Write Security Change with no success, so I don't really understand.

Permissions informations can be found in the following [technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787520(v=ws.10).aspx).

Did I miss something ?

Should I need to set Write permission on specifics properties I need to modify ? for example, set WP on password property to be able to reset/change user's password ?

Edit : Should I move this question to SuperUser ?

Comment: How are you trying to reset the password? Could you please describe the process?
Please try using DSMOD.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732954.aspx

Comment: Thanks for comment. I connected using the new user with ADSI Edit, then right click on the user > Reset Password. When I entered the password twice and click OK, I got a permission error.

Answer (score -2):

Had a similar problem and this helped me to solve it:

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Windows/microsoft.public.windows.server.active_directory/2006-05/msg01913.html

Comment: This is just a link. Links rot and die. You should actually post content.